# Linear independence of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, systems-of-equations, constraints

Say I have the following series of vectors $\left\{a,b,c,d,e\right\}$ with the following relations between them: $$a+b+c+d+e=0 \,\,\,\,\,;\,\,\,\,\, a \propto b\,\,\,\,\,;\,\,\,\,\,c=e\,\,$$ Then there exists three constraints among the five vectors so at most only two can be linearly independent. Now suppose we add another vector $k$ to the set, independent from the others. So now the dimensionality of the space spanned is $3$.

A possible spanning set is $\left\{k,a,e\right\}$ amongst many others but not e.g $\left\{k,a,b\right\}$.

Now construct the following four vectors $k+d, k, k+b+d+e$ and $k+a+b+d+e = k + d+ e + \rho b$, where $\rho$ is related to the proportionality constant between $a$ and $b$.

I find that these four vectors are linearly independent through solving the equation $\alpha k + \beta (k+d) + \gamma (k+b+d+e) + \delta (k+d+e+\rho b) = 0$ and finding $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=0$.

But why is this the case? Shouldn't they be linearly dependent because of the fact that $\text{dim}(\text{span} \left\{k,p_j\right\}) = 3$ which means I can create at most three linearly independent vectors and here I've used four?

Here $p_j$ is just any two appropriately chosen vectors out of the set $\left\{a,b,c,d,e\right\}$

Here is the working for solving of the constants:
Vector by vector I get the following equations $$\alpha + \beta +\gamma +\delta=0$$$$\beta + \gamma + \delta = 0$$$$\gamma+ \rho \delta = 0$$$$\gamma + \delta = 0.$$ The first and the second imply $\alpha=0$ while the fourth with the second imply $\beta=0$. Then the third subtracted from the fourth imply $\delta(\rho-1)=0$ and here I took $\delta=0$ because $\rho=1$ would imply $a=0$. (as $a+b=\rho b$ and so $a = (\rho - 1)b$).

Comment: What is $p_j$? How do you get the dimension to be three?

Comment: @Bemte Ah sorry I made an edit in my post. dim =3 because of the three constraints among a,b,c,d and e makes at most 2 linearly independent and then I added k so it's three. (I think!)

Comment: what does $a \propto b$ mean ?

Comment: @rapidracim, it probably means $a$ *is proportional to* $b$.

Comment: Yes, of course, by choosing only two vectors, you will get a dimenison of at most three... But you are given four vectors, one of them is $k$, not three, so I don't understand why you are using a total of three vectors now?

Comment: @rapidracim means vector a is proportional to b, ie they are related by a constant

Comment: The point is that only if $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=0$ is the ONLY solution to the vector sum equation, then the vectors are linearly independent. Have you checked that?

Comment: @Bemte I just meant to say that the four vectors are constructed out of the vectors in the set $\left\{k,a,b,c,d,e\right\}$ and a possible basis for this set is e.g $\left\{k,a,e\right\}$ of dimension three. But probably I'm not understanding some linear algebra somewhere.

Comment: Ah, so you mean that dim(span($\{a,b,c,d,e,k\})) = 3$ and thus we can not get dimension four? That is correct, yes, so you most likely have an error in your calculations...

Comment: @Andreas Yes, somewhere in the system I get the equation $\delta(\rho-1)=0$ so in principle I could have $\rho=1$ for non zero $\delta$ but this implies that $a=0$. (as if $a+b=\rho b$ then $a = (\rho-1)b$.)

Comment: @Bemte Thanks, that's what I meant - I'll post my full calculation in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note from the first condition that

$$
0 = a+b+c+d+e = (1 + \rho) b+d+ 2 e 
$$
, using  the other constraints.
So you cannot have $b,d,e$ as independent vectors in the equation 
you set up for your four vectors:

$$
\alpha k + \beta (k+d) + \gamma (k+b+d+e) + \delta (k+d+e+\rho b) = 0
$$

Instead, replacing for example $e$ from the first condition, you have

$$
\alpha k + \beta (k+d) + \gamma (k+b+d-\frac12 ((1 + \rho) b+d)) + \delta (k+d+\rho b - \frac12 ((1 + \rho) b+d)) = 0
$$

So you have four variables $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ but only three independent vectors $k,b,d$. So clearly $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=\delta=0$ is NOT the only solution. Therefore the four vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: Of course! Sorry, feel like I wasted everyone's time - thanks.

Comment: So just to check my understanding, basically it means only three vectors at most constructed out of $\left\{k,a,b,c,d,e\right\}$ can be linearly independent? Four or more are always linearly dependent and three or less are always linearly independent?

Comment: true, other than the last statement: "three or less are always linearly independent". Of course $a$ and $b$ are not linearly independent, and $c$ and $e$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: ah ok, so e.g $k, k+b,k+\rho b$ will be linearly dependent.

Comment: yes.........................

Comment: Thanks! So finally is there a generic condition on when one can tell if three vectors or less composed out of $\left\{k,a,b,c,d,e\right\}$ will be linearly independent or dependent? I would think the three vectors have to contain collectively three basis vectors at least. (e.g $k, k+b, k+\rho b$ only contained two so are linearly dep)

Comment: Oh sorry! Yes, I tend to upvote/accept after my questions in the comments were answered just to make sure I fully understood everything that was said.